# Click a button and it should load the content into the main content area

Tags: javascript

I have create 3 buttons on the left menu for "Cars," "Music," and "Games" 
When the user clicks one, it should load the appropriate contents into a DIV 
in the main content area. Each button should replace the contents of anything 
previously displayed in the div. I created my buttons, but I do not know how to 
load the content into the main content div or how to replace the previous content. 
Can you help please?

Comment: Where does the content come from? You should find some examples searching for `javascript dom replace content` (or similar). Also, there are tons of Ajax examples out there (if you use Ajax).

Comment: Hello there,the content comes from the buttons and loads in the main content area.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function

Comment: I'm not convinced that he's using jQuery; therefore `load()` probably isn't appropriate.

Comment: @David : I m just recommending op to use jquery.Make life simple

Comment: Then you should really explain *why* using jQuery, rather than the native DOM JavaScript/ECMAscript functions. Also: *how* to use `load()`, since your suggestion doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>  
<script>
    function load(url){
        $('#content').load(url);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>  
  <button onclick='load("url1");'>Content 1</button>
  <button onclick='load("url2");'>Content 2</button>

  <div id='content'></div>
</body>
```

**UPDATE** Ok lets clarify it a bit.

The code above uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) lib. Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more info about **load** function.

If you cannot or dont want to use jQuery look [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html) for JS solution.

If you want to use only static content then you have two another options:

```
//1: if the new content is only small portion of info text
<script>
  function load(newContent){
     document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = newContent;
  }
</script>
<button onclick='load("some text 1");'>Content1</button>
<button onclick='load("another text 2");'>Content2</button>

<div id='content'></div>

//2: put content directly to your page the several DIVs and hide them
<script>
  function show(index){
     var n=2; // number of DIVs

     //show desired content and hide any others   
     for(var i=1; i<=n; i++){
        document.getElementById('content'+i).style.display = i == index ? 'block' : 'none';
     }
  }
</script>

<button onclick='show(1);'>Content 1</button>
<button onclick='show(2);'>Content 2</button>

<div id='content1'></div>
<div id='content2' style='display:none;'></div>
```

Comment: Care to add an explanation? Also, this assumes that the OP is using jQuery.